# Windows XP RDP sound

Tags: windows-xp, audio, remote-desktop

At the XP computer and in the RDP terminal the sound icon is showing. However, when I'm logged in through RDP, I cannot hear any sounds from the session either from the RDP client or at the XP host computer. Where can I go to configure sound? Can it be done in gpedit.msc? I looked there but didn't find it. I would prefer to have the sounds play on the XP host but playing sounds to the RDP client will also work, so long as I can get sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the initial RDP dialog, where you enter the address of the machine to which you want to connect, there is an **Options** button.  Click that and go to the **Local Resources** tab.  Choose the appropriate setting for **Remote computer sound**.

Comment: I'm using Linux to connect so it doesn't look like that but yeah the option is configured from the client side.